# how to get tornado 211g (ACX111) working in mint 13 xfce?

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, xfce

I have mint 13 xfce installed on my thinkpad r31. For this laptop, I have a Tornado 211g pcmcia wireless adapter. This is not installed automatically in Mint and I am searching for a way to get this card working.

How Can I achieve this?

I have the windows XP drivers and have added these using ndiswrapper but so far, nothing has happened.

in terminal, I have typed *lspci* which returned my wireless adapter as an ACX111 chipset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like ACX100/ACX111 drivers probably won't ever be in the mainline kernel. Some [controversy](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/acx1xx) about legality of the reverse engineering exists.

That said, you might want to look at [this GitHub project](https://github.com/pld-linux/acx). If you use a kernel version no greater than 2.6.24, that might work for you.  I believe I used it successfully a few years ago on a Slackware 12.something laptop.

Comment: thanks. i found a mention on the mint community mentioning that acx111 was working perfectly. but how?  that was not there...

Answer (score 0):

it seems Ndiswrapper can not use the 32 bits XP driver with a 64bits Kernel!
So, to solve that on my 64 distribution with a PCI card Netgear WG311v2 embedding same ACX111 your wireles adapter,
I achieved configuration using gitHub project [like described here](http://www.mageialinux-online.org/forum/topic-18541+wifi-impossible-de-trouver-l-interface-ndiswrapper.php#m178345)

Comment: Whilst this may answer the question, [it is preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.